# Access beginner's questions

Tags: ms-access, vba

im doing my intership. My job right now is to develop a access application for tools control in a factory. Several questions here:

1. For a front end/back end structure, i use the external data link in Access and it act as if the tables are local, so i dont need to set up connection or recordset in code like i did before in Excel?
2. For a table i have index like 405679, it's better to set it in numeric or text?
3. If my application will run just on a Access runtime, is there any restriction in the development?
4. My boss wants that my application can automatically open one ERP software and fill in some blank (date, tool id, tool price etc.). Is it possible? (I dont think so...)
5. I know it's better to learn from example. Apart from the Northwind, where can i find other example Access applications and codes? (i do some search but what i found are just little app to show a specific technique, not a complete system)

im using Access 2003 (possibly upgrade to 2007)

Thanks!

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, it's a bit alarming to me to imagine a beginner developing a control system for factory tools based on Microsoft Access. No disrespect intended. Make sure you get some expert assistance from someone with experience of systems of this kind. Seriously reconsider whether Access Jet/ACE is really a sensible way to do this. There are other development environments and database platforms which are commonly used and designed for this kind of application.

Comment: @dportas:i dont have other choice. What we have here is only a shared folder in intranet, that's all. The servers are in the company headquarter. My back end is just a mdb file with only tables in that shared folder... And nobody here has done something big with Access...

Comment: Of course you have a choice. There are always choices. The fact that you aren't considering any alternatives shows that you do need some help. So hire someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer yours questions

1) Once you link the tables they will work almost exactly like a local table so you can make queries on them etc. There are some restrictions on access them through DAO code but that’s easy to get round if you need to

2) If its is a number only and not shown to the end user then use an autonumber field, that will give you a 32bit number to play with

3) Nope, anything you do in the full fat version of access will be able to be run on the runtime version so no worries there

4) Depends on the ERP system, if it has a web service attached to it or some kind of API then it would be possible. As a real worse case you could even do some automated button pressing but I would not recommend it!

5) Sorry I don’t know if any more example databases but the northwind one is a good learning tool

Let me know if you need any more detail

Comment: Thanks for quick response!! The index is a nature one, is what we use as tool id.

Comment: No worries. As for the key, so long as it is unique and is not going to change ever then it makes a good choice as a primary key on the table.

Comment: One more thing, i think it's better to use SQL sentence to fetch data in a FE/BE structure, for example a button that excute a sql sentence to the database, than using bound forms, is that correct?

Comment: That is a bit of a religious things within the access world! Personally I prefer to use unbound forms and get the data through code but there are those that will argue the opposite. Of course both have their pros and cons but as I said I personally prefer unbound forms and code

Comment: I'm one of those that will argue against unbound forms, at least to some extent. The question one really needs to ask is, why use unbound forms? What benefit will be gained? If you find yourself using unbound forms and trying to separate your code into different layers (which is a good practice) you're probably better off programming the application in Visual Studio since you can bind forms controls directly to objects. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: @HK1: Yes that's it.. But it takes more time in learning i think. And more important is, my colleges know only Access, if i make it in .NET, i go away, nobody can do the maintainance job. But since you mentioned it, can you recommend me some books or websites on this topic (vb.net as a front end)? Maybe i can try it out.

Comment: If you're worried about someone at the office understanding your application, bound forms are easier to do in Access than through code. You can still use a query/sql to limit the data the form binds.

Comment: If you can fill in a form using your mouse + keyboard, you can fill it in automatically using Access... it's just a question of how you want to do it. Web forms are basically the easiest, but it's not hard to automate mainframe sessions, or even proprietary apps. You'll want to look up APIs for whatever the third-party program is and, failing that, use either the Win32 API, or good, old SendKeys to get the task done. (My boss wrote something that used SendKeys + mouse clicks to perform ~100k database updates/month in some evil proprietary windows apps, so anything is possible.)